# the shape of grouby object and its transformed dataframe object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

There is a groupby object `B` returned by groupby operation. I printed its length, which is 6. Then I transformed this groupby object into dataframe type, then I printed the shape of this transformed dataframe object, the shape does not match the original groupby object. I am confused. Please see the related code and result, thanks.

```
print('type of B', type(B))
print('len(B) ',len(B))
b=B.apply(pd.DataFrame)
print('type of b', type(b))
print('b shape' , b.shape)
print('len(b) ',len(b))

type of B <class 'pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy'>
len(B)  6
type of b <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
b shape (84, 99)
len(b)  84
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is `groupby` object, it will equal to the number of unique `groupby` key when you apply `groupby`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,2]})
len(df.groupby('a'))
Out[49]: 2
len(df.groupby('a'))==df.a.nunique()
Out[50]: True
```

After we `apply(pd.DataFrame)`, the groupby object change back to dataframe, so it will equal to the same length of b